# Record collection in javascript

Tags: javascript

You are given a JSON object representing a part of your musical album collection. Each album has a unique id number as its key and several other properties. Not all albums have complete information.

You start with an updateRecords function that takes an object like collection, an id, a prop (like artist or tracks), and a value. Complete the function using the rules below to modify the object passed to the function.

1.Your function must always return the entire object.
2. If prop isn't tracks and value isn't an empty string, update or set that album's prop to value.
3. If prop is tracks but the album doesn't have a tracks property, create an empty array and add value to it.
4. If prop is tracks and value isn't an empty string, add value to the end of the album's existing tracks array.
5. If value is an empty string, delete the given prop property from the album.

Note: A copy of the collection object is used for the tests.

```js
var collection = {
  2548: {
    albumTitle: 'Slippery When Wet',
    artist: 'Bon Jovi',
    tracks: ['Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name']
  },
  2468: {
    albumTitle: '1999',
    artist: 'Prince',
    tracks: ['1999', 'Little Red Corvette']
  },
  1245: {
    artist: 'Robert Palmer',
    tracks: []
  },
  5439: {
    albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
  }
};

function updateRecords(object, id, prop, value) {
  
  if(prop !== 'tracks' && value !== "") {
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  }
  if(prop === 'tracks' && collection[id][prop] === undefined) {
    collection[id][prop] = [value];
  }
  if(prop === 'tracks') {
    let track = collection[id][prop];
    track.push(value)
  }
  if(value === "") {
    delete collection[id][prop]
  }
  console.log(collection)
  return collection;
}
updateRecords(collection, 5439, 'artist', 'ABBA');
updateRecords(collection, 2548, 'tracks', "");
updateRecords(collection, 2468, 'artist', "");
```

what's not working is:-

1. After updateRecords(collection, 2548, "artist", ""), artist should not be set
2. After updateRecords(collection, 2548, "tracks", ""), tracks should not be set

Comment: I have tested it. It seems to work. I have tested it in firefox console.

Comment: Here is the link to the question. Apply this code there and you will find 2 case not working. check it out and do reply please with the answer. 
 https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/record-collection

Comment: Seems to work. If you look at the last collection printed, you can see that 2548 does not have a `tracks` property and 2468 does not have an `artist` property.

Comment: i just did and the edited by derpirscher still shows that 2548 has artist named assigned  BON JOVI which should not be the case as the program requires artist should not be set in 2548. it's not working, try running it in the website I commented above

Comment: That might be in that specific test scenario because you are not modifying and returning the collection given in the parameter `object` but the global `var collection` ...

Comment: will you please write the code in working for all test case scenario and share?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good. But you missed one point here. The object being passed in the updateRecords method is named `object`. but you are updating an object named `collection`. You have two option you can either rename the parameter to `collection` like this,

```
function updateRecords(collection, id, prop, value) { // changed here.
  
  if(prop !== 'tracks' && value !== "") {
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  }
  if(prop === 'tracks' && collection[id][prop] === undefined) {
    collection[id][prop] = [value];
  }
  if(prop === 'tracks') {
    let track = collection[id][prop];
    track.push(value)
  }
  if(value === "") {
    delete collection[id][prop]
  }
  console.log(collection)
  return collection;
}
```

Or you can rename all the reference of `collection` in your `updateRecords` method to `object`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```js
function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
  if(prop !== 'tracks' && value !== "") {
    records[id][prop] = value;
  }
  if(prop === 'tracks') {
    if (typeof records[id][prop] === 'undefined') records[id][prop] = [value];
    else records[id][prop].push(value);
  }

  if(value === "") {
    delete records[id][prop]
  }

  return records;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
if (value === ""){
   delete records[id][prop];
} else if (prop !== "tracks" && value !==""){
    records[id][prop] = value;
} else if (prop === 'tracks' && value !== ""){
if (records[id].hasOwnProperty("tracks") === false){
  records[id][prop] = [];
}
  records[id][prop].push(value);
}

 return records;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
// Setup
var collection = {
  2548: {
    albumTitle: 'Slippery When Wet',
    artist: 'Bon Jovi',
    tracks: ['Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name']
  },
  2468: {
    albumTitle: '1999',
    artist: 'Prince',
    tracks: ['1999', 'Little Red Corvette']
  },
  1245: {
    artist: 'Robert Palmer',
    tracks: []
  },
  5439: {
    albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
  }
};

// Only change code below this line
function updateRecords(object, id, prop, value) {
  if (prop != "tracks" && value != "" ){
     object[id][prop]= value;
   } else if (prop =="tracks" && !(object[id].hasOwnProperty('tracks')))   {
    var tracks=[];
    object[id]["tracks"]= [value];
  }else if (prop=="tracks" && value != ""){
  object[id][prop].push(value);
  } else if (value === ""){
    delete object[id][prop];
  }

  return object;
}
```

updateRecords(collection, 5439, 'artist', 'ABBA');

Comment: That is the answer

Comment: Plz add some explanations for your answer. Otherwise, ppl might not be able to understand your answer.